# Fullcalendar - Drag event to different week in agendaWeek view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to drag a fullcalendar event to a different week while in agendaWeek view?

I have created a basic implementation of fullcalendar where it is possible to drag within the given week but it is not possible to move the event to a different week; how should I approach this issue? (Without using month view as it is not possible to drag to a certain time in this view)

http://jsfiddle.net/wbse7uy7/2/

```
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  editable: true,
    selectable: false,
      allDaySlot: false,
  //header and other values
      events: [
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-10-13T10:30:00',
                end: '2014-10-13T12:30:00',
                allDay: false
            }],

});
```

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/wbse7uy7/3/

Comment: Thanks but that only drags in the same week - I'm looking for a way to move to the next week when the drag reaches the edge of the calendar

Comment: Any updates to this, Smithy? I'm wondering how to achieve this too - it scares me that this was asked 2 years ago with no response...

Comment: This functionality is already asked on fullcanlendar here [link](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2542)